# What should I call an interface that creates an instance

Tags: java, oop, interface

What should I call an interface that has an abstract method that returns a new instance of a class?

For example, I have `Foo` class, which `execute`s an instance of `Parser` class that implements `Runnable`, which is created by a class implementing `ParserXXX` interface. (Not directly creating a `Parser` instance, in order to allow to use custom `Parser`) What should I call the `ParserXXX`?

```
@FunctionalInterface // >Java 8
interface ParserXXX {
    Runnable get(Data data);
}

class Parser implements Runnable {
    ...
}

class Foo {
    private ParserXXX;

    public Foo() {
        xxx = new ParserXXX() { // anonymous class
            @Override
            public Runnable get(Data data) {
                return new Parser(data);
            }
        }
        xxx = Parser::new; // using method reference(>Java 8)
        xxx = data -> new Parser(data); // using lambda function(>Java 8)
    }

    private void parse(Data data) {
        execute(xxx.get(data));
    }
}
```

I thought of following, but they don't see to fit:

- ParserSupplier: Supplier takes no argument
- ParserConstructor: Not always a constructor
- ParserBuilder, ParserFactory
- ParserGenerator, ParserProvider, ParserCreator

Also is this a common design pattern or an anti-pattern?

Comment: You could call it ParserFactory. You could also make the return type of the get method Parser rather than Runnable.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`ParserFactory` is the most common nomenclature used for the example you have given since it very closely matches the [Factory Pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factory_method_pattern). As mentioned in the comments, the more common way of expressing this pattern is to return an object of type `Parser` rather than simply `Runnable` and calling the method that creates the `Parser` `createParser` (or even just `create`) rather than `get`. Conventionally, `get` refers to obtaining an existing object (i.e. a private field holds a value and it is returned such that two subsequent calls to `get` return the *same* object, until the field is reassigned) rather than creating a new object for each call.

For example, the common way of expressing this pattern would resemble the following:

```
@FunctionalInterface
interface ParserFactory {
    Parser createParser(Data data);
}
```

Using this style, an instance of `Data` can be parsed as follows:

```
Data data = // ...
ParserFactory factory = // ... using your anonymous inner-class ...
Parser parser = factory.createParser(data);
parser.run();
```

Even if calls to `createParser` are stored as `Runnable` rather than `Parser`, this factory representation would still be valid, since `Parser` is a `Runnable`. For example, the both of the following calls to `createParser` are valid:

```
Data data = // ...
ParserFactory factory = // ...

Runnable runnable = factory.createParser(data);
Parser parser = factory.createParser(data);
```